# Certain vertices aren't registering for weight paint

Tags: modeling, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I'm trying to weight paint a model and it works for the most part but at random vertices or faces, it will refuse to paint over or change. I'm still relatively new, so I don't know if there's something I'm missing in the settings or something like that, or if that's not how weight paints work, I really don't know.

edit: here's a screenshot, I'm trying to set the weights to 0, but on the corner closest and the bottom of the far side won't paint[image]

Comment: Hello, could you please share some screenshots or share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Just from the screenshot, my guess is that you need to add geometry to your mesh. I would add a bunch of subdivisions or apply a subsurface modifier. This will allow it to have enough faces for your weight painting to take on more complex characteristics.